# Git post clone modification

Tags: git

I have a project which contains a folder by name Plugins.
I need to clone this git and when it is cloned.

1. I like to have a top level folder by name eclipse
2. Then, I like to rename it to "plugins" from "Plugins" and have contents as,

   ```
   <Git-folder>/eclipse/plugins/folders_contents
   ```

   Currently it is:

   ```
   <Git-folder>/Plugins/folders_contents
   ```

Comment: For the eclipse part, i can add the info in clone to clone it in, Top_Level_Folder/eclipse. But issue is to rename to "plugins" from "Plugins", i,e to small p from capital P

Comment: If the filesystem is not case sensitive on search (NTFS, HFS by default) the only way to change the case of a file/dir name is to do it in two steps: first rename the file/dir using a temporary name then rename it again to the desired name.